# (', CROSS, FULL, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, ON, RIGHT or USING expected, got 'WITH'

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have SQL request

Here is part of the code of it

```
    LEFT JOIN       dbo.contacts_client_organization cog WITH(NOLOCK)
ON              cog.clientid = be.clientid
```

After cog I have an error

> '(', CROSS, FULL, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, ON, RIGHT or USING expected, got 'WITH

I want to rewrite the query to use it on Amazon Redshift

Here is the full query

[Code of query](http://pastebin.com/rYGU4uCk)

How I can solve it?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use SQL Server specific functionality on a MySQL database?

Comment: `dbo.xxx` looks like SQL Server syntax.  Are you really using MySQL?  Also, please include the entire query, unless it's massive, in which case include enough to get the point across.

Comment: I try to rewrite MSSQL query to use it on redshift @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rYGU4uCk 
Here is full request @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Redshift uses PostgreSQL, so restrict yourself to PostgreSQL syntax and you'll be closer to working. PostgreSQL documentation is readily available online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nolock hint is not needed in Redshift (or Postgres).

Due to their underlying architecture, readers never block writers and writers never block readers, so the hint that enables a non-locking read in SQL Server is not needed for Redshift and Postgres

Just remove the `WITH(NOLOCK)` there is no equivalent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL your query would work fine. But for MYSQL if you need transaction isolation please try like below:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
select ...

 LEFT JOIN       dbo.contacts_client_organization cog WITH(NOLOCK)
ON              cog.clientid = be.clientid;
COMMIT ;
```

Comment: I need to write `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;` at start of query?

Comment: I think as I use Redshift and its PostgreSQL, it not fit for me?

Comment: @EugeneSukh May be this might help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394565/postgresql-equivalent-of-sqlservers-nolock-hint